# Set width of "Dialog" widget to a percentage of the page in Vaadin 14

Tags: css, dialog, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In Vaadin 14, the `Dialog` widget opens properly when specifying width and height by `px` ([CSS virtual "pixels"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_pixel)).

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
dialog.setCloseOnEsc( true );
dialog.setCloseOnOutsideClick( true );
dialog.add( new Label( "whatever" ) );
dialog.setWidth( "500px" );                //   width
dialog.setHeight( "700px" );               //   height
```

Unfortunately, changing that `500px` to `80%`:

```
dialog.setWidth( "80%" );                  //   width as percentage (%)
dialog.setHeight( "700px" );               //   height
```

I expect the dialog to now take up most of the browser's windows widthe. I get just the opposite. Results in the dialog's width being about **only a third** of the window **rather than 80%**. And the width is fixed, unchanging as the user resizes the browser window.

➥ How can I get a `Dialog` to fill most but not all of the browser window, and be dynamic resized as the user grows/shrinks the window's width/height?

---

## Example

Here is an entire working example app based on a "plain Java Servlet" starter project provided by the Vaadin.com site.

```
package work.basil.example.dialog_by_percent;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dialog.Dialog;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;

/**
 * The main view contains a button and a click listener.
 */
@Route ( "" )
@PWA ( name = "Project Base for Vaadin", shortName = "Project Base" )
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout
{

    public MainView ( )
    {
        Button buttonPx = new Button( "Dialog by px" ,
                event -> this.dialogByPx()
        );

        Button buttonPercentage = new Button( "Dialog by px" ,
                event -> this.dialogByPercentage()
        );

        add( buttonPx , buttonPercentage );
    }

    private void dialogByPx ( )
    {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        dialog.setCloseOnEsc( true );
        dialog.setCloseOnOutsideClick( true );
        dialog.add( new Label( "px" ) );
        dialog.setWidth( "500px" );                //   width
        dialog.setHeight( "700px" );               //   height
        dialog.open();
    }

    private void dialogByPercentage ( )
    {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        dialog.setCloseOnEsc( true );
        dialog.setCloseOnOutsideClick( true );
        dialog.add( new Label( "percentage (%)" ) );
        dialog.setWidth( "80%" );                  //   width
        dialog.setHeight( "700px" );               //   height
        dialog.open();
    }
}
```

When run.

[image: screenshot of demo app]

### `dialog.setWidth( "500px" )`

[image: screenshot of demo app opening a <code>Dialog</code> with px]

### `dialog.setWidth( "80%" )`

[image: screenshot of demo app opening a <code>Dialog</code> with percentage]

Comment: On a related note: [*How to correctly specify dialog size in vaadin-flow*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55631881/642706)

Comment: Maybe `80vw` as width works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I get a Dialog to fill most but not all of the browser window, and be dynamic resized as the user grows/shrinks the window's width/height?

By setting width/height to `overlay` part of the `vaadin-dialog-overlay` using CSS.

**A longer version**

---

The behavior you see is a consequence of style being applied to the `div`  inside a `flow-component-renderer`, not the `overlay` part as one would expect. The relevant tickets are:

- [setWidth and setHeight either not working, or are wrongly documented](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-dialog-flow/issues/144)
- [Add a note that 'setWidth' sets a width to a 'flow-component-renderer', not an overlay/dialog itself](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-dialog-flow/issues/139)

If you inspect the dialog having fixed width in DevTools, you will notice that the dialog itself is actually wider.

The *correct* (I mean it is correct, but not expected) way would be to style an `overlay` part of the dialog via css using:

```css
[part="overlay"]{
    width:80%;
}
```

and

```java
@CssImport(
    value= "./styles/dialogOverlay.css", 
    themeFor = "vaadin-dialog-overlay"
)
```

After that, the width is taking `80%` as expected. I hope the screenshot above illustrates the issue better:

[image]

---

Comment: How did you graphically inspect the rendered UI  as shown in your screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate a bit what do you mean by inspecting here? It's just regular DevTools of Chrome and I put cursor on top of `div`, so it got highlighted.

Comment: Yes, the visual debugging display. That answers it, thanks.